# Quick Question on Quotient Space

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, group-theory

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $U \subseteq X$. What is the quotient space $X/ U $like when $X=U$? Is it just like $X$? So is it trivially a normed linear space?

Thanks!

Comment: But taking quotient doesn't preserve the norm though.

Comment: Right! What is the quotient space $X/X$ like then?

Comment: It's the zero vector space equipped with the zero norm. (This is the unique norm on the zero vector space because it's the unique answer compatible with scalar multiplication.) This is the terminal object in the category of normed vector spaces and weak contractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $U$ is linear subspace of $X$, $X/U$ is just a notation for the quotient $X/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the relation in $X$ given by $x \sim y$ iff $x-y \in U$. So, given $x \in X$, $$X/X = \{[x]\}.$$

Comment: So $X/X$ only consists of 1 element, since there's only 1 equivalence class? Is that right?

Comment: @2pirsquared That's right, for any pair of elements $x,y$ in $X$ we have $x-y \in X$, so $[x] = [y]$.

Comment: Also note that $X \setminus X = \{X\}$.